# Xamarin.iOS: Try to move bottom toolbar(text field) above keyboard when editing like chat window

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I tried to put the toolbar(with text field) above the keyboard. Initially, the toolbar was at the bottom.

I tried to use "inputAccessaryView" on the text field. The toolbar just disappear after I clicked inside the text field. I know this will work if I created a new toolbar for it. But like in the chat window, I want the same textfield/toolbar.

[image]

Here is the code

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    NavigationItem.Title = "Name";
    ChatInput = new UITextField (new RectangleF(0,0,View.Bounds.Width - 104f,30f));
    Toolbar = new UIToolbar (new RectangleF(0, View.Bounds.Height - 44.0f, View.Bounds.Width, 44f));
    ChatInput.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect;

    Toolbar.SetItems( new UIBarButtonItem[] {
        new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Refresh, (s,e) => {
            Console.WriteLine("Refresh clicked");
        })
        , new UIBarButtonItem (ChatInput){Style = UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered,Width = View.Bounds.Width - 104f}
        , new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Reply, (s,e) => {
            Console.WriteLine ("Reply clicked");
        })
    }, false);
    ChatInput.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Send;
    ChatInput.ShouldBeginEditing = delegate {
        ChatInput.InputAccessoryView = Toolbar;
        return true;
    };

    ChatInput.ShouldReturn = delegate {
        ChatInput.ResignFirstResponder();
        return true;
    };
    View.AddSubview (Toolbar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a way to pin the toolbar on top of the keyboard, but what you could do it create some kind of method to move the toolbar (edit its .Frame property) when the keyboard pops up. I use this method to move an entire `UIScrollView` up. You can find the method I used here: (http://www.gooorack.com/2013/08/28/xamarin-moving-the-view-on-keyboard-show/).

This may not be the most "clean" solution, but if implemented correctly, it does its job. Another advantage is, is if you put the entire "moving of the keyboard" in a separate class-file, you can re-use it in other views.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Love and regards,
Björn